# How to perfom claculation with data coming from 2 different tables in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to calculate the ratio of some features in postgresql but using data from 2 different tables.

From `table 1` I want to query all the count of all rows:

```
select count(*) as total from table1
```

and then perform a calculation with the `total` calculate above, like this:

```
select count(class) / total as ratio
from table2
```

So the `total` comes table1 and `count(class)` comes from table2:

How can I do this as there's no common fields to join them?

Comment: `select count(class) / count(table1.*) as ratio from  table1, table2`. Though if there is no relation between them it anybody's guess what the result means?

Answer (score 0):

Use subqueries:

```
select
    (select count(class) from table2) /
    (select count(*) as total from table1) as ratio
```

It could be that `count(class)` should be `count(distinct class)`, if not `count(class)` can be just `count(*)`.